# iOS 6 : compatibility issue with AddSubView

Tags: iphone, addsubview, ios6

I am trying to make my **iPhone** app compatible with **iOS 6**, the problem is that when I use `addSubview` method, the height of view added is 460 by default.
but I dont want to set the frame manually for all of my application views. 
what do you suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am having the same issue using ios6/XCode 4.5.

I have a `addSubview` in landscape and even though  the .xib is set to `autoResize`, it shows with the width for 3.5" displays.  The main view fills the 4" screen fine.